# Prime Ideals as Ring theoretic Ultrafilters

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, category-theory

I am confused by the following statement in Awodey's Category Theory p. 35:

> Ring homomorphisms $A\to \mathbb Z$ into the initial ring $\mathbb Z$ play an analogous and equally important role [to that of boolean algebra morphisms $B\to \mathbb 2$] in algebraic geometry. They correspond to so-called **prime ideals**, which are the ring-theoretic generalizations of ultrafilters.

This is particularly confusing to me since there are many rings which seem to have no morphisms to $\mathbb Z$. For example, any field has no unital ring morphisms into $\mathbb Z$ since units are preserved by ring morphisms.

Comment: The statement is simply incorrect. Prime ideals are generalisations of ultrafilters, but not for the given reason.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, this is a curious misstatement, considering the text Category Theory is in its 2nd edition and it is not contained in the list of errata on Awodey's website http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/